# SharedPreferences not working. Always show the same value

Tags: java, android

This is my MainActivity.java's onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
loadSavedPreferences();
        savePreferences("storedAddress", userAddress.getText().toString());

}
```

These 2 are the methods inside the class

```
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String address = sharedPreferences.getString("storedAddress", "YourAddress");
        userAddress.setText(address);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Here's the flow. First time user uses the app has to enter their address in the EditText field. I want the same address to be stored there when the user returns.

The problem with the code above: It always shows "YourAddress" in the EditText field. There's no login required for this application. Just a simple form.

Comment: Dont use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(). Use getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE); in both load & save

Comment: @cxphong I changed it but there's error Error:(163, 17) error: method getSharedPreferences in class PreferenceManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: okay now no error but still showing "Your address"@cxphong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `savePreferences()` method in any action the user can do after typing his address,a button click or whatever.

The way it is now, it's saving only when the activity gets created and after you load the preferences with the default value `YourAddress`. That's why you always get the same value.